# electrobot amd ryzen 5 3600 nvidia geforce rtx 2060 super 8gb gaming tower pc with a 550 watt power supply + 24" lg ultragear 1ms 144hz

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, power-supply, power, windows-10-pro

i have

a electrobot amd ryzen 5 3600  nvidia geforce rtx 2060 super 8gb gaming tower pc with a 550 watt power supply + 24" lg ultragear 1ms 144hz gaming monitor + zebronics transformer m gaming mouse

do i need a
1100va / 1100c : 230v : 660 watt
ups
to
run my ,
cpu
550 watt power supply
properly

Answer (score 1):

Most UPSs are able to handle a single computer, even if it is a gaming computer. (Some brands will even market their UPS as a gaming UPS). That being said, **a UPS is not required to run your system.**

In the event of a power loss/outage, a typical UPS will continue to run your system for around 10 more minutes. If you have experienced power outages often, you could purchase a UPS to protect your computer's components. However, if you lose power you would need to shutdown your computer before the UPS ran out of power.

Alternatively, you can purchase a UPS that has a data port. You would then be able to install the software that came with the UPS to enable your computer to automatically shutdown your PC gracefully (safely) before the UPS ran out of power.